# problemas con nodemailer

Tags: nodejs, nodemailer

Cree una aplicacion con node.js v18.15.0 y angular usando ionic, pero al usar ionic serve me salen mensajes de error con crypto, stream y otros más.

el problema es que me dice que hay problemas con estos, pero busque por la documentacion de node y estos deben ya venir integrados en la version que estoy usando.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

export const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
    user: 'psudeayuda@gmail.com',
    pass: 'hhijkzzrgfnllxmu'
    }
});


const mailOptions = {
    from: 'aula@tmcapacitacion.cl',
    to: 'aula@tmcapacitacion.cl',
    subject: 'Prueba de correo 1.1',
    text: 'Este es el primer correo de pruebas'
};


transporter.verify().then(() => {
    console.log('LISTO EL SISTEMA');
})


transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, () => {
    null;
});
```

si uso el comando node email.ts se envia el correo bien, pero so lo intento colocar en un servicio me sale el mensaje de error:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/xoauth2/index.js:3:15-39 - Error: Module not found: Error:             
Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\joxsa\Desktop\TMCapacitacion\webCapacitacion\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\xoauth2'
[ng]
[ng] BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
[ng] This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
[ng]
[ng] If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
[ng]    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
[ng]    - install 'stream-browserify'
[ng] If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
[ng]    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
[ng]
[ng] ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/xoauth2/index.js:5:15-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\joxsa\Desktop\TMCapacitacion\webCapacitacion\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\xoauth2'
[ng]
[ng] BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by     default.
[ng] This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
[ng]
[ng] If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
[ng]    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
[ng]    - install 'crypto-browserify'
[ng] If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
[ng]    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

-----------------------------------------------servicio:-----------------------------------------------

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import { transporter } from './email';
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmailService {

constructor() { }

transporter = nodemailer;

async generar(){

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
  user: 'psudeayuda@gmail.com',
  pass: 'hhijkzzrgfnllxmu'
  }
});

    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'psudeayuda@gmail.com',
      to: 'psudeayuda@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Correo de prueba',
      text: 'este es el contenido'
    };

try {
  const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  console.log('Correo enviado:', info.response);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error al enviar el correo:', error);
}
}

}
```